# Stability of the explicit MacCormack Scheme to solve the Navier Stokes equations with Wilcox's K-Omega Turbulence Model

Tags: fluid-dynamics, stability, numerical-modelling, explicit-methods

I am solving turbulent pipe flow with an explicit MacCormack scheme and Wilcox k-omega model. The laminar version of the code had three distinct stability criteria which worked fine after implementation.

Now, the turbulent version seems to have stability problem. I tried to upgrade the stability criteria for the new set of equations, but it seems that solution eventually blows up. I have noticed the omega values grow very large through all the domain.

Does anybody know if there are new stability conditions with k-omega model, or I should merely extend MacCormack stability to the new equations?

Also I appreciate it if anyone can introduce a paper or book that discusses two-equation models stability.

Comment: In general, I don't recommend explicit timestepping for complicated flows, such as those requiring a turbulence model.  If a coupled solver is infeasible, you should use a segregated solver (e.g. PISO).  Also, which Wilcox k-omega model are you using?  2006?

Comment: Thanks Paul. I understand that implicit may be a better option but at this point I cannot really change the whole scheme. I am using the older version of Wilcox model (1993) but it can be updated to the most recent one without much complication. Do you think the newer model is more stable?